# Laravel : Make Model, Migration, controller (custom path), seeder in one line

Tags: laravel-5.8, laravel-artisan

Is that possible to make model, migration, seeder and controller in custom path like "Admin/UserController" in one line ?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is but not by default. you can create your own artisan command that will automatically run `make:model -m` and `make:controller Custom/Path` command.